# wpf-Xaml line is not showing up while running the code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have started learning wpf. I am trying to use line element but whenever i try to run this code line is not visible at all. Same case with rectangle, I have used rectangle element as well but it is also not showing up. What is the problem? I don't understand. I am able to see that in designer view but not in the runtime.

```
<Window x:Class="Mi_Express.Product_Details"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mi_Express"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Product_Details" Height="1920" Width="1080" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" 
        Foreground="White" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold"  Topmost="True"  Background="White">
    <Grid>

        <Line HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="870" Y2="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" Margin="120,180,79,1712"/>
        <Label Content="Shopping Cart:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="157,125,0,0" FontSize="30" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>


        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="center" Height="73" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1017" Margin="28,1663,35,0"
             />
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="102" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139"  Margin="157,270,0,0"/>

        <Button   Content="Go Back" ClickMode="Press" Background="#FFE87E04" BorderBrush="#e87e04" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" Margin="157,1786,0,0" Height="61"/>
        <Button   Content="Continue" ClickMode="Press" Background="#e87e04" BorderBrush="#e87e04" FontSize="18" Foreground="white" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Margin="0,1786,159,0" Height="61"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the structure of your grid ..Dont apply margin to any of the UI elements over here.. instead remove it and use grid.column to position your UI elements..I have modified your code a litte

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Line Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="870" Visibility="Visible" Y2="10" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="4" Margin="12,18,79,171"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Shopping Cart:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="157,125,0,0" FontSize="30" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>


    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2"
               Visibility="Visible"
               Fill="Blue"
              HorizontalAlignment="center" Height="73" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1017" Margin="28,166,35,0"
         />
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="102" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139"  Margin="157,270,0,0"/>

    <Button   Content="Go Back" ClickMode="Press" Background="#FFE87E04" BorderBrush="#e87e04" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" Margin="157,1786,0,0" Height="61"/>
    <Button   Content="Continue" ClickMode="Press" Background="#e87e04" BorderBrush="#e87e04" FontSize="18" Foreground="white" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Margin="0,1786,159,0" Height="61"/>

</Grid>
```

For more information on how to use grid in wpf .. please follow this links:

1) http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/grid-layout-in-wpf/

2) http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/

3) https://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Comment: I have tried this, but still it is invisible. is there anything else?

Comment: which version of visual studio are you using??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the margin. Bottom margin is way too high and line goes out of the window

I guess you mistaken height with width and you ment Width="1920" Height="1080". Even so the actually height of the grid it would not be 1080, you can check it using this line

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="157,175,0,0" FontSize="30" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
```